# Relation belongs to table with double primary key in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to store in a database the weekly hour of an user. For example, the user A work at monday from 8:00am to 17:00pm, on tuesday from 9:00am to 11:00am ecc...

For do this I created two table:
Users (id, username, ecc...)
Hours (user_id, day, start, end) with "user_id" and "day" as primary key.

Instead of create another table called Days with only 7 records (one for each day).
My problem is to define the relation with laravel, indeed if I use three tables I can use Many to Many relation, but if I use this form how I can specific that "day" column is a key?

Comment: Instead of `day` as primary key use it to mark the day (int 1-7) maybe?

Comment: Yes, day column is an integer, but my problem is to define the relation method.

Comment: I just read the full title... there is no such thing as double primary key. are talking about a composite key?

Comment: I think primary key composed by two column :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest following table structure of `Hours`

```
id        (primary key, auto-increment)
user_id 
day       (NOT primary key, values from 1-7)
start
end
```

Then you can add a UNIQUE index over the combination of `user_id` and `day`.

SQL: `ALTER TABLE hours ADD UNIQUE unique_user_day (user_id, day);`

Laravel schema builder (migration): `$table->unique(array('user_id', 'day'));`

After that you just need a normal relation. Nothing fancy at all.

```
public function hours(){
    return $this->hasMany('Hours');
}
```

This is how you get all hours

```
$hours = Users::find(1)->hours;
```

And then, when you need a specific day, add a where statement

```
$tuesday = Users::find(1)->hours()->where('day', 2)->get();
```

Or for a nicer syntax you could a function to your users model

```
public function day($number){
    return $this->hours()->where('day', $number)->get();
}

$tuesday = Users::find(1)->day(2);
```

You could even work with constants for the weekdays...

Comment: Cool! Didn't know about the $table->unique(array('x', 'y')); possibility!

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it's not in the documentation. Found it browsing Laravels source code...